# Adding style to div element in React ParticleJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to add style to the div element which gets created while adding particle component in React. I am adding the style in Component and not in the options params provided by tsparticles. But the height and visibility properties is getting added to the canvas. Please see attached screenshot in the post.

[image]

```
<Particles
      className="react-particles"
      id="particles-js"
      style={
        {
          visibility: "hidden"
        }
      }
      options={{
        background: {
          color: {
            value: "#3e1110"
          },
        },
        fpsLimit: 60,
        interactivity: {
          detectsOn: "canvas",
          events: {
            onClick: {
              enable: false,
              mode: "push",
            },
            onHover: {
              enable: false,
              mode: "repulse"
            },
            resize: true
          },
          modes: {
            bubble: {
              distance: 400,
              duration: 2,
              opacity: 0.8,
              size: 40,
            },
            push: {
              quantity: 4,
            },
            repulse: {
              distance: 200,
              duration: 0.4
            }
          }
        },
        canvas:{
          w: "500",
          h: "500"
        },
        particles: {
          number: {
              value: 40,
              density: {
                  enable: true,
                  value_area: 800
              }
          },
          color: {
              value: "#722035"
          },
          shape: {
              type: "edge",
              stroke: {
                  width: 0,
                  color: "#000000"
              },
              polygon: {
                  "nb_sides": 5
              },
              image: {
                  src: "img/github.svg",
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50
              }
          },
          opacity: {
              value: 0.749690259550659,
              random: true,
              anim: {
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 1,
                  opacity_min: 0.1,
                  sync: false
              }
          },
          size: {
              value: 5,
              random: true,
              anim: {
                  enable: false,
                  speed: 3,
                  size_min: 1,
                  sync: false
              }
          },
          line_linked: {
              enable: false,
              distance: 150,
              color: "#ffffff",
              opacity: 0.4,
              width: 1
          },
          move: {
              enable: true,
              speed: 3,
              direction: "top-right",
              random: true,
              straight: false,
              out_mode: "out",
              bounce: false,
              attract: {
                  enable: false,
                  rotateX: 600,
                  rotateY: 1200
              }
          }
      },
      interactivity: {
          detect_on: "canvas",
          events: {
              onhover: {
                  enable: false,
                  mode: "repulse"
              },
              onclick: {
                  enable: false,
                  mode: "push"
              },
              resize: true
          },
          modes: {
              grab: {
                  distance: 400,
                  line_linked: {
                      opacity: 1
                  }
              },
              bubble: {
                  distance: 400,
                  size: 40,
                  duration: 2,
                  opacity: 8,
                  speed: 3
              },
              repulse: {
                  distance: 200,
                  duration: 0.4
              },
              push: {
                  particles_nb: 4
              },
              remove: {
                  particles_nb: 2
              }
          }
      },
        detectRetina: true,
      }}
    />
```